# What is the difference between the solution of an ODE and its steady state?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what is the difference between of this. I am not good in mathematics

Comment: the steady state is a special kind of solution which happens to be constant. You are very good at mathematics, don't even try to hide it !